# Selection Args as integers not string

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have this method that takes an integer input and returns the row, it should take the employee id and returns its name, title, phone, email.
Meanwhile rawquery selection args use strings and doesn't work with integers, how can i fix that?

```
 public Cursor getEmpData(Integer ID)
        {
            EmpDept = getReadableDatabase();
            Integer[] empRow = {ID};

            Cursor c = EmpDept.rawQuery("Select name, Title, phone, email from Employee where EmpID like ?", ID);
            if (c != null)
            {
                c.moveToFirst();
            }
            EmpDept.close();
            return c;
        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The 2nd argument of `rawQuery` must be an array of `String`:

```
Cursor c = EmpDept.rawQuery("Select name, Title, phone, email from Employee where EmpID like ?", new String[] {ID.toString()});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `toString()`, like with any other Object:

```
Cursor c = EmpDept.rawQuery("Select name, Title, phone, email from Employee where EmpID like ?", ID.toString());
```

If you decide to use the primitive `int` instead, `String.valueOf(ID)` will do the same thing.